# Codeigniter SELECT can't handle this query

Tags: codeigniter

I've tested the following SQL in phpMyAdmin and have confirmed that it works fine. However, when I try to use it in CodeIgniter as follows, I get error messages.

```
$this->db->order_by("vch_name", "asc");
$this->db->select('SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_contact WHERE fk_client_id = tbl_pro_client_id) AS count_contacts FROM tbl_pro_client');
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_pro_client', $num, $offset);
    return $query;
```

Is this too complicated for a CI select, or is there a way around it? A more obvious answer of course is that I'm probably doing something incredibly stupid. And advice, pointers, etc greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the actual fields you want to select should be given to the `select()` call (ie the `SELECT` keyword and `FROM ...` should not be there). Something like;

```
$this->db->order_by("vch_name", "asc");
$this->db->select('*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_contact WHERE fk_client_id=tbl_pro_client_id) AS count_contacts', false);
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_pro_client', $num, $offset);
return $query;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I even added another select because I now understand the syntax better.

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about database query manipulation [click here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

`limit` parameters are looking wrong, CI provide `limit()` function, try this code 
And in `select()` function no need **FROM table_name**, and Use `FALSE` to skip (`)

```
$this->db->order_by("vch_name", "asc");
$this->db->select('SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_contact WHERE fk_client_id = tbl_pro_client_id) AS count_contacts', false);
$this->db->limit($num, $offset); 
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_pro_client');
return $query;
```

Comment: Thanks; I used the format in the answer below $this->db->select('*, .... etc rather than select('SELECT *, ... etc and this worked fine. Your answer works also. Note that there is no problem with the LIMIT parameters.